# How to configure uwsgi to work with a specific version of python?

Tags: python, django, debian, uwsgi

I use Debian 9 uwsgi and nginx as a server for several Django sites. By default, Debian has python 3.5. uwsgi installed globally

```
sudo -H pip3 install uwsgi
```

I've decided to transfer the sites to python 3.7. To do this, I installed a new version of python 3.7 from the source files into the */usr/local/bin/python3.7* folder.

I also recreated a virtual environment (with the same name as before)

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.7 protrack
```

But now I've got an error , uwsgi still uses python 3.5 .

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-13 15:06:55 UTC; 3 days ago
  Process: 2102 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown gk:www-data /run/uwsgi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2106 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 1 vassals"
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─2106 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
           ├─2110 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini
           ├─2112 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini
           ├─2113 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini
           ├─2114 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini
           ├─2115 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini
           └─2116 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini myblog.ini

Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/protrack.sock fd 3
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: setuid() to 1001
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Python version: 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Set PythonHome to /home/gk/Env/protrack
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Current thread 0x00007fd43cf73b40 (most recent call first):
Снж 16 16:21:59 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Mon Dec 16 16:21:59 2019 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance protrack.ini (pid: 22782)
Снж 16 16:22:02 server-1537436012497-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01 uwsgi[2106]: Mon Dec 16 16:22:02 2019 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance protrack.ini
```

How do I reconfigure uwsgi to use python 3.7?

**/etc/uwsgi/sites/protrack.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
project = protrack
uid = gk
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/protrack
module = protrack.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

# Finish off the configuration with the following lines
socket = /run/uwsgi/protrack.sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install uwsgi to your virtualenv directory (instead of the global one) & configure it for using in nginx. This will make sure that uwsgi & your python versions are the same.

Comment: nope, just install a new one and configure your `system` scripts to work with the new installed one.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how _configure your system scripts to work with the new installed one_

Comment: I mean fix the binary path in your `/etc/init.d/uwsgi` or etc script to the virtualenv uwsgi instance instead of system global

Comment: Hm, I havn't uwsgi in /etc/init.d/ folder

Comment: ah, then you can forget about the suggestion :)